# Calculating time in minutes between two dates in R (POSIXct format)

Tags: r, datetime, time

I'd like to calculate the time in minutes between two events in R, by only doing so only for a specific id (e.g. 892530) and between the event 'eventBegins' and the first human2 event (or, another way to write this would be for the minimum datetime for human2). Note that the 'datetime' variable is in POSIXct format. I don't seem to be able to do this using a mix of dplyr and base R (min()) and would like to pick your brain for solutions. Lastly, I'm trying to get an average of the time difference for each id in the dataset.

Here is an output generated using the code `dput(head(df, 30))`
:

```
structure(list(visitor_id = c(175464, 175464, 175464, 892530, 
892530, 892530, 892530, 892530, 892530, 1006916, 1006916, 1006916, 
1336852, 1336852, 1336852, 2370624, 2370624, 2370624, 3347200, 
3347200, 3347200, 4539320, 4539320, 4539320, 4539320, 4539320, 
4666936, 4666936, 4666936, 4697670), event_type = c("human1", "human1", 
"human2", "human1", "eventBegins", "human1", "human2", "human2", "eventEnds", "human1", 
"human1", "human1", "human1", "human1", "human1", "human1", "human1", "human1", "human1", 
"human1", "human1", "human1", "eventBegins", "human2", "human2", "human1", "human1", 
"human1", "human1", "human1"), datetime = structure(c(1618678444, 
1618678444, 1618678444, 1617980667, 1617980668, 1617980668, 1617980668, 
1617980679, 1617980679, 1617530138, 1617530138, 1617530138, 1617299837, 
1617299837, 1617299837, 1617621792, 1617621792, 1617621792, 1618145874, 
1618145874, 1618145874, 1619013964, 1619013964, 1619013964, 1619014004, 
1619014005, 1617282418, 1617282418, 1617282418, 1619543098), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), row.names = c(NA, 30L), class = "data.frame")
```

Please let me know if you have ideas about how to solve this - I am running out of ideas. TIA.

Comment: Would you be so kind and `dput()` your dataframe and post it here.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Thanks! Bit of a newbie here but I'll have a look and will try to improve my post to make it clearer.

Comment: can you also be a bit more clear on "I'm trying to get an average of the time difference for each id 1 in the dataset" . Do you want to get the average for each id for all humans or only for humans2?. It is usually very helpful to write one or two equations to make it a bit more concrete and avoid ambiguity. :)

Comment: Probably something like this from your example (which doesn't currently work for me): 

df %>% group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(event_begins_per_id = min(datetime[event == "eventBegins"]), 
         time_diff = datetime - event_begins_per_id, 
         avg_time_diff_per_id = mean(time_diff[!event %in% c("eventBegins", "eventEnds")])) %>% summarize(mean_time_diff = mean(avg_time_diff_per_id, na.rm = TRUE)) 

Though I think this wouldn't work to get an average for all ids because of 'group_by(id)'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**edit:** using sample data from OP.

comments: do you think you can work with the following? If not, try to write (per hand) a data frame with the expected results.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% group_by(visitor_id) %>% 
  mutate(event_begins_per_id = min(datetime[event_type == "eventBegins"]), 
         time_diff = datetime - event_begins_per_id, 
         avg_time_diff_per_id = mean(time_diff[!event_type %in% c("eventBegins", "eventEnds")]))
```

#### Results

```
# A tibble: 30 x 6
# Groups:   visitor_id [9]
   visitor_id event_type  datetime            event_begins_per_id time_diff avg_time_diff_per_id
        <dbl> <chr>       <dttm>              <dttm>              <drtn>    <drtn>              
 1     175464 human1      2021-04-17 16:54:04 NA NA               -Inf secs  -Inf secs          
 2     175464 human1      2021-04-17 16:54:04 NA NA               -Inf secs  -Inf secs          
 3     175464 human2      2021-04-17 16:54:04 NA NA               -Inf secs  -Inf secs          
 4     892530 human1      2021-04-09 15:04:27 2021-04-09 15:04:28   -1 secs  2.50 secs          
 5     892530 eventBegins 2021-04-09 15:04:28 2021-04-09 15:04:28    0 secs  2.50 secs          
 6     892530 human1      2021-04-09 15:04:28 2021-04-09 15:04:28    0 secs  2.50 secs          
 7     892530 human2      2021-04-09 15:04:28 2021-04-09 15:04:28    0 secs  2.50 secs          
 8     892530 human2      2021-04-09 15:04:39 2021-04-09 15:04:28   11 secs  2.50 secs          
 9     892530 eventEnds   2021-04-09 15:04:39 2021-04-09 15:04:28   11 secs  2.50 secs          
10    1006916 human1      2021-04-04 09:55:38 NA NA               -Inf secs  -Inf secs          
11    1006916 human1      2021-04-04 09:55:38 NA NA               -Inf secs  -Inf secs          
12    1006916 human1      2021-04-04 09:55:38 NA NA               -Inf secs  -Inf secs          
13    1336852 human1      2021-04-01 17:57:17 NA NA               -Inf secs  -Inf secs          
14    1336852 human1      2021-04-01 17:57:17 NA NA               -Inf secs  -Inf secs          
15    1336852 human1      2021-04-01 17:57:17 NA NA               -Inf secs  -Inf secs          
16    2370624 human1      2021-04-05 11:23:12 NA NA               -Inf secs  -Inf secs          
17    2370624 human1      2021-04-05 11:23:12 NA NA               -Inf secs  -Inf secs          
18    2370624 human1      2021-04-05 11:23:12 NA NA               -Inf secs  -Inf secs          
19    3347200 human1      2021-04-11 12:57:54 NA NA               -Inf secs  -Inf secs          
20    3347200 human1      2021-04-11 12:57:54 NA NA               -Inf secs  -Inf secs          
21    3347200 human1      2021-04-11 12:57:54 NA NA               -Inf secs  -Inf secs          
22    4539320 human1      2021-04-21 14:06:04 2021-04-21 14:06:04    0 secs 20.25 secs          
23    4539320 eventBegins 2021-04-21 14:06:04 2021-04-21 14:06:04    0 secs 20.25 secs          
24    4539320 human2      2021-04-21 14:06:04 2021-04-21 14:06:04    0 secs 20.25 secs          
25    4539320 human2      2021-04-21 14:06:44 2021-04-21 14:06:04   40 secs 20.25 secs          
26    4539320 human1      2021-04-21 14:06:45 2021-04-21 14:06:04   41 secs 20.25 secs          
27    4666936 human1      2021-04-01 13:06:58 NA NA               -Inf secs  -Inf secs          
28    4666936 human1      2021-04-01 13:06:58 NA NA               -Inf secs  -Inf secs          
29    4666936 human1      2021-04-01 13:06:58 NA NA               -Inf secs  -Inf secs          
30    4697670 human1      2021-04-27 17:04:58 NA NA               -Inf secs  -Inf secs
```

Comment: Thank you for this! The code doesn't seem to work, as it returns 'returning Infno non-missing arguments to min' -  is this because of the POSIXct format? 

To answer your question above, I want the time difference between eventBegins and the first (min time) human2 for id '1' -- So time at line 4 minus time at line 2 in your tibble above. Then I want to do the same for id 2 by finding the difference between the first 'human 2' (not shown) and eventBegins (line 10). Then I want to calculate an average of those time differences across all ids (1, 2, etc.). Apologies if this wasn't clear.

Comment: Also not sure how to modify my code to make it reproducible... :/ I'm an R (& Stack Overflow) newbie, but appreciate your quick response! Will look into videos to show me how to improve my post next time.

Comment: No need to apologise :) to make it reproducible, run `dput(head(df, 30)`  for the 30 first rows of your data frame, assuming it is called `df`. Then edit your question and append at the very end the output of `dput(...)` to your question. With that, I will be able to work with a sample of your data. For clarification: why the human2 in line 9 (id=2) should not be taken into consideration? because it comes up before "eventbegins"? So the logic is taking only the human2 AFTER eventbegins, for all id's?

Comment: Ok, thanks for the detailed info! I've run dput() as suggested and appended the output to my question. 

Yes exactly, I only want to know the time that has elapsed in minutes between the event 'eventBegins' and the first time 'human2' appears (earliest or minimum time). And so yes, human2 on line 9 would not be considered as it appears before the first 'eventBegins' for id 2 in your example above. I wonder what I was missing from your example that prevented the code from working on the data (and gave me the error above)? I'd like to understand. Thanks!

Comment: The "no non-missing" warning is because some visitor_ids are unique and has no "eventBegins" related to it (for example id 175464), but that is just warning and will result in missing values.

Comment: Right. Is there a way to block this warning? It appears numerous times and seems to result in my R crashing since I have billions of rows so I have to stop the code while it's running... Other option I can think of is to create a subset with only IDs that have 'eventBegins'. 

Thanks for all of your help with my original question, two thumbs up! :)

Comment: you can use suppressWarnings() to do that, but the warnings shouldn't be the reason why the code is crashing.